# How do I pull up an email view by clicking on an email in iOS?

Tags: ios, email, swift

I've seen this done before, but I just want to click on a button or a string of someone's email and have an email view pop up with the email address already entered into the "to" line. I'm trying to do this without leaving the app and going into the Mail app

Comment: I don't have an example at hand, but you create an instance of the [email view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html).  (Took all of ten seconds to Google the doc and a bunch of tutorials.)

Comment: I googled stuff for an hour before posting this. Guess I was doing it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I just Googled "ios email view controller".